# docker php image with all content and connecting to nginx

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I use dockerfile for creating docker image.

I copy in this file my src - to docker

COPY ./ /app

so I have image with all content.

Now i want start second container nginx but this config:

```
 location / {
                root /app/public;

                try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
            }

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
                client_max_body_size 50m;
                fastcgi_pass php:9000;
```

dont work - nginx dont have access to content of php container.

Is possible to run nginx if all files is inside php container ?

Answer (score 0):

You want use nginx as reverse proxy ?

Comment: i what provide html output from my container.

Comment: what's " provide html output " ? see what's file in the application or navigate in your application ?